# How to change modal text dynamically in angular 7

Tags: angular6, angular5, angular7

I am trying to change attribute value by viewchild method but not working.I do not how to do that? Example i want to change modal popup title dynamically.How to do it? many time tried but i do not know how to do it? please anyone can help to find solution?

Comment: Please show some code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the title string in `openModal` method and further use it in your views.

```
openModal(id: string, title: string) {
    this.modaltitle= title;
    this.modalService.open(id);
}
```

You can use `{{modaltitle}}` in your view to show display the title.

```
<modal id="custom-modal-1" modaltitle="Test title">
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h1>{{modaltitle}}</h1>
        <p>
            Home page text: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="bodyText" />
        </p>
        <button class="button" (click)="closeModal('custom-modal-1');">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-background"></div>
```

You can seed the updated demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iybx4hangular6-custom-popup-rnf6rh?file=src/app/app.component.html